# data guard configuration Error: ORA-16778: redo transport error for one or more members

Tags: database, oracle, dataguard

Database version: 19c. Data guard configuration with error:

```
DGMGRL> show configuration

Configuration - config1

  Protection Mode: MaxPerformance
  Members:
  actc          - Primary database
    Error: ORA-16778: redo transport error for one or more members

    actc_unq1   - Physical standby database
      Warning: ORA-16809: multiple warnings detected for the member

Fast-Start Failover:  Disabled

Configuration Status:
ERROR   (status updated 53 seconds ago)
```

log_archive_dest2 = service="actc_stby1", ASYNC NOAFFIRM delay=0 optional compression=disable max_failure=0 reopen=300 db_unique_name="actc_unq1" net_timeout=30, valid_for=(online_logfile,all_roles)

The TNS name "actc_stby1" is fine, I can do tnsping and also connect to the standby database using sqlplus sys@actc_stby1. But looks like the redo transport service is not aware of this TNS name. I am adding the TNS entry to the IFILE of tnsnames.ora file and it has only one IFILE entry.

If I bounce the active database, then the redo transport service is aware of the TNS entry and the configuration status becomes successful.

This active DB cannot be bounced as this is the main source database. Ideally, when I add a new standby database, I would like to add TNS entry to IFILE and add the standby database configuration in the DG configuration without bouncing the DB. Is there a way to do that or am I missing anything when adding TNS entry?